# What is string of json ？

Tags: json

1 :

```
"{\"currentCity\":\"\U5317\U4eac\U5e02\",\"latitude\":\"39.784277\", \"userId\":\"81d911a3-9731-4153-85bc-b095614f020e\",\"longitude\":\"116.518057\",\"operationType\":\"2\"}"
```

2 :

```
{"currentCity":"Beijing","latitude":"39.784277","longitude":"116.518057","userId":"81d911a3-9731-4153-85bc-b095614f020e","operationType":"2"}
```

Question： Which is a json string ？

Comment: Both.  The first one is escaping double quotes, which you might need to do with a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The first one. The second one is a string representation of a Javascript object. When you *parse* the first one, the second one is what you get (a Javascript object).

Comment: They are both JSON, valid depending on the context.  The second is what you might send to a web service from a UI, while the first is what you might actually code into a JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

First one is the string representation of JSON object with escaping character to escape double quotes , while second one is java script  object already , if you prettify second you see proper representation like this

```
{
    "currentCity": "Beijing",
    "latitude": "39.784277",
    "longitude": "116.518057",
    "userId": "81d911a3-9731-4153-85bc-b095614f020e",
    "operationType": "2"
}
```

You can check and play with your JSON here: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer